# Javax mail extract msg attachment

Tags: outlook, jakarta-mail, attachment, msg

I have a mail class using javax mail and I’m trying to save an msg attachment. When I send an msg attachment using outlook 2016, it seems that outlook sends it as an `elm` file. I can read it fine but when I try to open the file with outlook it complains that the email is locked.

Has anyone experienced this?  Why does outlook send the file as eml?  I can open it in a text editor but not in outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was saving the message as `msg` while it was in `eml` format.  The point is that when you attach an `msg` file from outlook, it will be sent as an `msg`